# Non-Arg constructor Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, default-constructor

I am calling a constructor in a method to insert new nodes.While I am adding new node default constructor is creating new node with default values . I want to just insert values using insert method as in below code . Is there any way I may avoid first node being default.

```
class Node {
    Node right, left;
    int data = 0;
    Node() {

    }
    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void insert(int value) {
        if (value <= data) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new Node(value);
            } else {
                left.insert(value);
            }
        } else {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new Node(value);
            } else {
                right.insert(value);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Node new_node=new Node();//creating first node with 0 value
        new_node.insert(5);
        new_node.insert(4);
        new_node.insert(9);
        new_node.insert(23);
        new_node.insert(70);
        new_node.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) (is one possible solution).

Comment: but there is no "default constructor" in that code!  nor a "Non-Arg constructor"!

Comment: You could create a constructor with an initial value that makes sense (Let's say, `-1` assuming that your list doesn't contain it): `Node() { data = -1; }`. But you'll have to avoid the first element for all operations. See my answer.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks for pointing , changed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the first value as the first element:

```
Node new_node = new Node(5); // create 1st node with 1st value
```

Or you could define a new default constructor with a value that you don't expect to be in the list (let's say `-1`), but you'd have to be careful about this element in your list *that is not really part of the list*, and that makes implementing other operations trickier:

```
Node() { data = -1; }
```

But all this is symptom of a bigger problem: you shouldn't handle the head of your list in the `Node` class. It'd be better to create a new class, let's call it `MyList` and define a `Node head` attribute on it, and all insert/update/delete/search operations should be implemented on that class.

It's important to keep the head separate, because there will be operations that modify the `head`. For example, your `insert()` method doesn't consider the case when the node to insert should go at the beginning of the existing list.

Comment: So there won't be any way where  new_node can  be used only as reference and node insertion is done through insert() method only  in above scenario?

Comment: No, `new_node` should be the `head` attribute in the `MyList` class. Think about it, how else would you handle the case when a new node needs to replace the current head of the list, because it has to be inserted in the first position?

Comment: OK  , thanks  .I thought I am making mistake somewhere.

Comment: I can do something like this to point to head node , root can be head node-                                       Node() {
 if(root==null) {
 root=this;
 }
        
    }

Comment: No, you shouldn't really keep the head in the Node class, it'd be better if you have a separate class for the head and the operations, and the Node is just for storing the data and the basic functionality for connecting/disconnecting the nodes to the left and right.